# Choose model by BIC in a stepwise algorithm after choosing model from glmnet

Tags: r, glmnet, stepwise-regression, bic

I have data where number of observation `n` is smaller than number of variables `p`. The answer variable is binary. For example:

```
n <- 10
p <- 100
x <- matrix(rnorm(n*p), ncol = p)
y <- rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = 0.5)
```

I would like to fit logistic model for this data. So

```
model <- glmnet(x, y, family = "binomial", intercept = FALSE)
```

The function returns 100 model for different lambda values (panalization parameter in lasso regression). I choose the biggest model which has `n - 1` parameters or less (so less than number of observations). Let's say chosen model is for `lambda_opt`.

```
model_one <- glmnet(x, y, family = "binomial", intercept = FALSE, lambda = lambda_opt)
```

Now I would like to do the second step - use `step` function to my model to choose the submodel which will be the best in term of BIC. Unfortunately `step` function doesn't work.

```
step(model_one, direction = "backward", k = log(n))
```

How can I make it work? Is there some other function for this specific kind of model to do what I want?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Do you not trust the results of glmnet?  In any case, `step` is expecting an `lm` or `glm` type object, as is explicitly stated in the documentation.

Comment: I am doing some simulations and it seems that generally if I choose model from glmnet with lambda_min from cv.glmnet it is still too big. So I came up with this approach.

Comment: What does "too big" mean?

Comment: It means that I generated data, so I know exactly what  coefficients vector looks like and the model chooses too many of coefficients.